# Can we train AI near the Sun?

Tags: thermodynamics, sun, efficient-energy-use

Considering the high energy demands of AI training, which can reach several megawatts, I'm curious about the idea of sourcing this energy directly from space, particularly from near the Sun.

Take, for example, the Parker Solar Probe. It orbits about 4 million miles from the Sun, where it's exposed to much stronger sunlight than we get on Earth. This could potentially make solar energy collection more efficient for high-energy needs.

The probe uses special solar panels with a cooling system to manage the extreme heat. This technology intrigues me for its potential application in a space-based solar power station.

Could such a project be feasible? How much more efficient would it be to collect solar energy at this distance from the Sun compared to on Earth? And considering the unique technology of the solar panels used by the probe, could we make a rough estimate of how this might work?

Comment: *Can we train Ai near the Sun?* How could it be impossible? The cost effectiveness of doing so doesn’t seem like a physics problem. I would assume that if it were cost-effective, someone would be making plans to do it soon.

Comment: *...potential application in a space-based solar power station.* uh, how do you plan on getting the power back to earth?

Comment: The energy needed to train AI comes from the need to use lots of computer time. It is expensive, but easily done from electric power available in a building if you have the money. The power in the sunlight at the Parker solar probe is enough to melt a computer. Way too much power.